# Should I use APC to cache long prepared SQL strings

Tags: php, caching, import, dataset, apc

Kind of a two-parter here. I'm working on a project (PHP/Postgres) where I'm loading mid-size csv files into our system (5k - 100k lines). These csv records are to be inserted into a table with approximately 100 columns (7 of which compose the primary key). These files are not guaranteed to contain unique records, and upserts need to be done on the records as needed.

I've implemented [an upsert similar to this](http://xzilla.net/blog/2011/Mar/Upserting-via-Writeable-CTE.html), that uses a prepared statement to cut down on running time, and have the system loading around 800 records per second. This is sufficient for the smaller files, but not so for files with 100k+ lines.

In profiling my code, I noticed a significant amount of time was being spent simply constructing the long sql prepared statements, so I decided to use the APC user cache to cache them, improving my running time significantly. I've also used prepared statements to improve performance. [Here is approximately how I have implemented this.](http://pastebin.com/7jZHq0Rn)

So here are the questions:

1. Should I be using the APC user cache aggressively to cache any particularly large constructs that can be built infrequently?
2. Are there more efficient ways of performing upserts on 100-column, 100k-line files?
3. Could I store the files differently? (perhaps using hstore to bulk-store all but the 7-8 more important columns in the file)

**Edit**: [Here's the code including how the sql statements are constructed.](http://pastebin.com/zsRzhZSD)

Comment: Creating an SQL statement shouldn't be that slow. There's probably something wrong about how you're going about that part -- can you include that in your sample code?

Comment: Good point. Appended code to the post.